# LWJGL - VBO rendering on one system but not the other

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I recently decided to revisit some LWJGL rendering code I wrote using Indexed VBOs based off of a tutorial on the LWJGL wiki. Everything worked as expected on my desktop computer, but when I switched to my school laptop it refused to render anything.

I have the following render code:

GL20.glUseProgram(pId);
        System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

```
    // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the vertices and colors
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

    // Bind to the index VBO that has all the information about the order of the vertices
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiId);

    // Draw the vertices
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));
    // Put everything back to default (deselect)
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));
```

And here are my vertex/fragment shaders

```
#version 130
uniform mat4 MVP;
in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
out vec4 pass_Color;
void main(void) {
gl_Position = MVP * in_Position;
pass_Color = in_Color;
}
#version 130
in vec4 pass_Color;
out vec4 out_Color;
void main(void) {
out_Color = pass_Color;
}
```

and this is my VBO initialization function

```
public void initialize(float[] vertices, float[] colors, int[] indices) {
    shaderSetup();
    //create the buffers to hold vertex color and index data
    FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
    verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
    verticesBuffer.flip();
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

    FloatBuffer colorsBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colors.length);
    colorsBuffer.put(colors);
    colorsBuffer.flip();
    // OpenGL expects vertices in counter clockwise order by default
    indicesCount = indices.length;
    IntBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indicesCount);
    indicesBuffer.put(indices);
    indicesBuffer.flip();
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

    // Create a new Vertex Array Object in memory and select it (bind)
    vaoId = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

    // Create a new Vertex Buffer Object in memory and select it (bind) - VERTICES
    vboId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

    // Create a new Vertex Buffer Object in memory and select it (bind) - COLORS
    vbocId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbocId);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorsBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));

    // Deselect (bind to 0) the VAO
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    // Create a new VBO for the indices and select it (bind) - INDICES
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));
    vboiId = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiId);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    System.out.println("NO Error? " + (GL11.glGetError() == GL11.GL_NO_ERROR));
}
```

Shader setup code:

```
int errorCheckValue = GL11.glGetError();
// Load the vertex shader
vsId = this.loadShader("Shaders/vertex.glsl", GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
// Load the fragment shader
fsId = this.loadShader("Shaders/fragment.glsl", GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
// Create a new shader program that links both shaders
pId = GL20.glCreateProgram();
GL20.glAttachShader(pId, vsId);
GL20.glAttachShader(pId, fsId);
GL20.glLinkProgram(pId);
// Position information will be attribute 0
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 0, "in_Position");
// Color information will be attribute 1
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 1, "in_Color");
GL20.glValidateProgram(pId);
errorCheckValue = GL11.glGetError();
if (errorCheckValue != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) {
System.out.println("ERROR - Could not create the shaders");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

My desktop at home (which renders everything as expected) is running an nVidia GTX 460 graphics card, and my school laptop (which doesn't render anything) has an AMD Firepro m4000 graphics card. My best guess is some part of the VBO render/creation/shader code is incompatible with my m4000 card, but I am unable to find any errors with glGetError().

Comment: Running the program on my girlfriend's laptop in eclipse also does not render anything. Her laptop has the same hardware as mine.

Comment: What about the driver version? This can also makes a difference. Are you sure there are not OpenGL errors? Where do you call glGetError(), and how many times do you do it? I suggest you populate your code with a few `glGetErrors()` just to make sure that there isn't any...

Comment: Do you have anything in the code that is not shown to ensure that `in_Position` is bound to location 0, and `in_Color` to location 1?

Comment: Dan, I just updated the video drivers and added in where I put some glGetError() checks. I just do a ctrl+F in the console for false and don't find anything. I also have one at the end of the code that links the shaders.

Comment: Reto,I added the shader setup code. It shows how I bind 'in_position' and 'in_color' to positions 0 and 1

Comment: @Loginaut Are you aware that calling glGetErrors() does NOT print anything unless you explicitly create a function to do so? Have a look at this example http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2013/01/29/debugging-opengl-using-glgeterror/

Comment: @RetoKoradi, so would something like
 
'int errorVal = GL11.glGetError();' 
'if (errorVal != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR))'
' System.out.println("OpenGL Error");'

work better? If so I am still not seeing any openGL errors replacing the print statements with that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of calls you have in the shader setup code will not work as intended:

```
GL20.glLinkProgram(pId);
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 0, "in_Position");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 1, "in_Color");
```

`glBindAttribLocation()` needs to be called **before** `glLinkProgram()` to take effect. From the [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml):

> Attribute bindings do not go into effect until glLinkProgram is called. After a program object has been linked successfully, the index values for generic attributes remain fixed (and their values can be queried) until the next link command occurs.

Therefore, the order of calls needs to be:

```
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 0, "in_Position");
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pId, 1, "in_Color");
GL20.glLinkProgram(pId);
```

While not a correctness issue, you're also not using VAOs very effectively. Attribute enable/disable values and the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding are part of the VAO state. So you can call `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiId)` once during setup, *while the VAO is bound*. Then in the draw call, you only need to bind the VAO to set up all the state.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks for the help! It's interesting that my desktop graphics card was able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: If the locations are assigned automatically, many implementations will assign them sequentially in order of occurrence. It's not overly surprising that you would get 0 and 1 by default. But others might assign them sequentially in alphabetical order. Or use something entirely different.